# Any way to fetch the through fields for an object linked via Many2Many field without knowing the column name in advance?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am trying to write a generic method that can take any Django Model and returns it in a dictionary form.

So for example, if my models are defined thus (very generic):

```
class A(models.Model):
    somefieldA = models.TextField()
    m2mfield = models.ManyToManyField(B, through='AandB')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.somefieldA


class B(models.Model):
    somefieldB = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.somefieldB


class AandB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    field1 = models.DecimalField()
    field2 = models.TextField()
    field3 = models.DateField()
```

Now, assume we have an instance of the object A `a_obj`.

I can get all the related B objects using:

```
# This loop is there because I am working with other fields as well.
def instance_to_dict(instance):
    for field in instance._meta.get_fields():
        if field.many_to_many:
             m2m_mgr = getattr(instance, field.name)
             for idx, assoc_obj in enumerate(m2m_mgr.all()):
                 assoc_obj_str = str(assoc_obj)
                 # How to obtain the related through field values?
                 # m2m_mgr.through.objects.get() would need prior knowlegde
                 # of field name so get(a=instance, b=assoc_obj) is not possible
                 # m2m_mgr.through.objects.all() fetches all the objects
                 # in the Many to Many manager.
```

And then call `instance_to_dict(a_obj)`. This method could be called by passing other models' instances.
Ideally, I would like to create a dict of the obj and related "through" fields for any object. Is this possible to do?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer so am just providing this suggestion:  try ManyToManyRel - https://kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.fields.reverse_related.ManyToManyRel.

Comment: @DanSwain Can you share a how this would work (I ask because I couldn't find a working example, not necessarily looking for how this would work in my situation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the explicitly defined `ManyToMany` manager, there is also an implicit reverse relationship for the `ForeignKey` from `AandB` to `A`. So you can do something like this:

```
for field in instance._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True):
    if field.one_to_many:  # reverse ForeignKey
        m2m_through_mgr = getattr(instance, field.get_accessor_name())  # e.g. aandb_set
        m2m_through_mgr.all()  # all related instances from the through table
```

Another approach is to go through the through table fields looking at [`field.related_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.related_model) to see which one points back to your original table.

This all gets quite messy, but there should be enough meta information to do what you want. One obstacle is that the API isn't fully documented. Specifically, relation fields are represented by instances of the `ManyToOneRel` class, which as of Django 2.1 remains undocumented for reasons hinted at in [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py#L184). Hence my use of the undocumented `get_accessor_name()` method.