# Find the field that connects a model to a "through" model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-1.8

Lets say I have models defined as:

```
# The class that I will have the instance of.
class A(models.Model):
    somefieldA = models.TextField()
    m2mfield = models.ManyToManyField(B, through='AandB')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.somefieldA


# The model that participates in the m2m field.
class B(models.Model):
    somefieldB = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.somefieldB


# Model that stores the extra information
# about the m2m rel.
class AandB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    field1 = models.DecimalField()
    field2 = models.TextField()
    field3 = models.DateField()
```

My requirement is to iterate through all the objects in the model `AandB`. I know that I can do that through ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52283964/3441488)):

```
# I have the instance of model A
for field in instance._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True):
    if field.one_to_many:
        mgr = getattr(instance, field.get_accessor_name())
        for obj in mgr.all():
            # Do stuff here.
```

My question is, is there any way I can get the field name through which `AandB` model is linked to model `A`? (Which in this case would be `m2mfield`).

Comment: Isn't that the value returned by `field.get_accessor_name()`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I want the field name which is `m2mfield`. What `field.get_accessor_name()` gives me is `AandB_set`.

Comment: Try `field.attname` maybe.

Comment: @schwobaseggl `AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52283964/3441488), and the idea that popped up after @schwobaseggl asked me a question in the comment section, I just decided to use the `related_name` property to make my life easier. Although I can't get the exact name of the field, but I can pass whatever name I like in the `related_name` to ultimately reach the conclusion I wanted to originally.

```
# Model that stores the extra information
# about the m2m rel.
class AandB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='name_I_like_here')
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    field1 = models.DecimalField()
    field2 = models.TextField()
    field3 = models.DateField()
```

And, then I can use `get_accessor_field()` to get both the related AandB models and also get to name the relation as I did above. This makes sense to me. I hope this also helps someone else.

In the mean time, if anybody has any other suggestions, please feel free to leave comments or an answer!